# How to get valueOf & values of an Enum and call methods on an interface it implements when defined as a generic class param

Tags: java, spring, generics, enums

I want to convert `String`s to `Enum`s for a set of enum types. I use an interface to mark what set of enums to convert and define a couple of methods used during conversion:

```
public interface SymbolEnum {
    String getCode();       
    String getDescription();
}
```

Here's an example of one of the `Enum` types that I want to derive from a `String`:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor // using lombok
public enum Element implements SymbolEnum {

    IRON("FE", "iron"), 
    HYDROGEN("H", "hydrogen"),

    @Getter
    private final String code;
    @Getter
    private final String description;

}
```

If the String matches the enum constant name, the enum code property, or the enum description property then I want to convert to that enum. Otherwise, the code should thrown an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I'm using Spring's `Converter` interface to implement my converter. `Converter` is parameterized as `Converter<S,T>`. What should I use for `T`? I know that `T` should extend `Enum` and implement `SymbolEnum`. Here's what I tried:

```
public class StringToSymbolEnum<T extends Enum<?> & SymbolEnum> implements Converter<String, T> {

    @Override
    public T convert(String source) {
        try {
            return T.valueOf(source); // compile error
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException notEnumConstant) {
            for (Enum enum : T.values()) { // compile error
                if (T.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(source) // compile error
                        || T.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(source)) { // compile error
                    return T;
                }
            }
            throw notEnumConstant;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass a description of the enum to the `StringToSymbolEnum` constructors. Perhaps either the `Class<T>` (for use in `Enum.valueOf`) or `T[]` from `values`.

Note, `T` should be defined:

```
T extends Enum<T> & SymbolEnum
```

Instead of using a wildcard.

Comment: to add, instead of `T.values()` they can use `.getEnumConstants()` from the `Class` object