# How to write a generic Spring converter that converts Strings to an enum that implements a given interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics, enums

As mentioned in [How to get valueOf & values of an Enum and call methods on an interface it implements when defined as a generic class param](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59779592/1706691), I want to convert Strings to Enums for a set of enum types. Although the answer in that post solved my compilation issues, Spring is not converting (please see update below). Here's the information from that post for reference:

I use an interface to mark what set of enums to convert and define a couple of methods used during conversion:

```
public interface SymbolEnum {
    String getCode();       
    String getDescription();
}
```

Here's an example of one of the Enum types that I want to derive from a String:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor // using lombok
public enum Element implements SymbolEnum {

    IRON("FE", "iron"), 
    HYDROGEN("H", "hydrogen"),

    @Getter
    private final String code;
    @Getter
    private final String description;

}
```

If the String matches the enum constant name, the enum code property, or the enum description property then I want to convert to that enum. Otherwise, the code should thrown an IllegalArgumentException.

I'm using Spring's Converter interface to implement my converter:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StringToSymbolEnum<T extends Enum<T> & SymbolEnum> implements Converter<String, T> {

    private final T[] values;

    @Override
    public T convert(String source) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(values[0].getDeclaringClass(), source);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException notEnumConstant) {
            for (T value : values()) {
                if (value.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(source) 
                        || value.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(source)) { 
                    return value;
                }
            }
            throw notEnumConstant;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's where I registered the converter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

      @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

          registry.addConverter(new StringToSymbolEnum<Element>(Element.values()));
        }           
}
```

But the converter is never called. How do I get Spring to use the converter?

**Update**

I would expect the converter to be called when an HTTP GET request is made to the following endpoint in the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/element")
public class ElementController {

    @NonNull
    private final ElementService elementService;

    @GetMapping
    public Element getElement(
            @RequestParam(name="element")
            Element element // During Spring's binding, I expect the registered converter to be called
            ) {
        return elementService.getElement(element);
    }

}
```

**Update 2**

I found a couple of solutions to this issue. One solution is to implement a Spring `ConverterFactory` and register it with the `FormatterRegistry`. However, that solution seems to be more appropriate for registering a single super type. In my example, I have classes that need to registered if they are of two types, `SymbolEnum` and `Enum`. Here's my attempt at that approach:

```
public class StringToEnumConverterFactory <R extends Enum<R> & SymbolEnum> 
    implements ConverterFactory<String, R> {

    @Override
    public <T extends R> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToSymbolEnumInner<T>(targetType.getEnumConstants());
    }

    private class StringToSymbolEnumInner <W extends R>
        implements Converter<String, W> {

        private final W[] values;

        public StringToSymbolEnumInner(W[] values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public W convert(String source) {
            log.info("called converter with values ");
            try {
                return (W) Enum.valueOf(values[0].getDeclaringClass(), source);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException notEnumConstant) {
                for (W value : values) {
                    if (value.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(source)
                            || value.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(source)) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                throw notEnumConstant;
            }
        }

    }
```

I don't like the cast and it's really not working as a factory since I have to register each `SymbolEnum` class.

The other option is to use more explicit registration as follows:

```
registry.addConverter(String.class, 
                    Element.class,
                    new StringToSymbolEnum<Element>(
                            Element.values()));
```

Both of these approaches work. That is, the converter gets called. Is there a better approach to this? Why doesn't my first attempt work? I'm wondering if it has something to do with type erasure.